# SQL Replace used during a compare

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace

I currently run this query:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = table2.columnA  
FROM table2
WHERE column2 = table2.columnA
AND column3 = table2.columnC
```

Yes there is a duplicate column, sorry.

When I cross reference `column2` with  `table2.columnA` there is a chance to get `NULL` because `column2` **DOES NOT** contain `/` where as `table2.columnA` **may** contain `/`

I don't want to change the data in `table2.columnA`

It is my understanding that I can run this query to `REPLACE` the characters.

```
SELECT REPLACE ([table2.columnA],'/','-')
FROM table2
```

It is necessary that this does not make a permanent change to  `table2` so I want to make sure that I am getting this right or to see if there is a better way.

Now I want to combine the two queries but am unsure how.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = table2.columnA  
FROM table2
WHERE column2 = (SELECT REPLACE([table2.columnA],'/','-')table2.columnA)
FROM table2
AND column3 = table2.columnC
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: General Rule Of Thumb: A SQL Statement can only ever change one(1) table.  Thus, `UPDATE TableX ...` can only ever change TableX, no matter what comes after that in the statement.  Likewise, `DELETE TableY ...` can only delete rows from TableY, and `INSERT TableZ ...` can only add rows to TableZ.  And a `SELECT` statement can ***never*** change the contents of a table, it can only return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
UPDATE table1  
SET column1 = table2.columnA   
FROM table1 
    inner join table2 
    on table1.column2 = REPLACE([table2.columnA],'/','-')
    and table1.column3 = table2.columnC
```

Comment: I get an error `msg 8114, level 16, state 5

error` converting  `nvarchar` to `float`  So I'm guessing this is a problem I didn't think about

Comment: Then one of your fields is a different type to one that you are comparing it with.

Comment: and that would be because I added the statement to the wrong line. lets try this again....