# How to compare SQL fields of different tables, then replace the with value other fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Situation: I am using wordpress and I have 60000 old posts. Now I have to update each posts with some new information. For some reason, I have to compare the custom fields in SQL and find the same post id. Then make the changes.

**SQL struction:**

table1(t1): wpxf_posts
column name1(c1): ID
column name2(c2): post_name

table2(t2): wpxf_postmeta
column name3(c3): post_id
column name4(c4): code

**What I have to do:**

1. Compare value of c1 and c3
2. if c1 = c3
3. then c4 = c2

Here is a picture to help to describe

[image]

I read some posts but most of them teach us how to compare the difference. I am not sure if they suit my case as it seems did not find the same value.
This one may be helpful but I don't know how to apply to my situation.
[SQL Replace used during a compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806975/sql-replace-used-during-a-compare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a case statement:

```
Update table2
Set c4 = Case When c1 = c2 Then c2 Else c4 End
From table2
     Join table1
          On (What ever column you should join on)
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.